# Differences between inactive vs disabled and active vs enabled services

Tags: systemd, exit-status, systemctl

I am confused by the concept of enabled or active and disabled or inactive.

Could someone explain it?

Comment: I've submitted a pull request to improve the [docs for `systemctl status`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/4950) in `man systemctl`, which seems like the obvious plan to look for these docs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The man page for `systemd` has the info that you're looking for.

*excerpt*

> systemd provides a dependency system between various entities called
>   "units".  Units encapsulate various objects that are relevant for
>   system boot-up and  maintenance. The majority of units are configured
>   in unit configuration files,  whose syntax and basic set of options is
>   described in systemd.unit(5), however  some are created automatically
>   from other configuration or dynamically from  system state.
>
> Units may be 'active' (meaning started, bound, plugged in, ... 
>   depending on the unit type, see below), or 'inactive' (meaning
>   stopped, unbound,  unplugged, ...), as well as in the process of being
>   activated or deactivated,  i.e. between the two states (these states
>   are called 'activating', 'deactivating').
>
> A special 'failed' state is available as well which is very  similar
>   to 'inactive' and is entered when the service failed in some way 
>   (process returned error code on exit, or crashed, or an operation
>   timed out). If this state is entered the cause will be logged, for
>   later reference.
>
> Note that the various unit types may have a number of additional
>   substates, which are mapped to the five generalized unit states
>   described here.

#### Breakdown

So if you've read the above and don't really understand the difference, here it is, in a nutshell.

- **enabled** - a service (unit) is configured to start when the system boots
- **disabled** - a service (unit) is configured to not start when the system boots
- **active** - a service (unit) is currently running.
- **inactive** - a service (unit) is currently not running, but may get started, i.e. become active, if something attempts to make use of the service.

#### inactive

This last one can seem like the most perplexing, but think of `systemd` along the same lines as `xinetd`. It can manage your services for you and start them up, on demand when needed. So while the services are "off" they're in the ***inactive*** state, but when started, they can become ***active***.

This state can also occur when a service (unit) has been enabled but not yet manually started. So the service lays "dormant" in the ***stopped*** or ***failed*** state until either the service is manually started, or the system goes through a reboot, which would cause the service to become ***active*** due to its enablement.

Answer (score 8):

When you enable/disable a service, you essentially tell whether to automatically start at boot.

So, `systemctl enable lxdm` will set LXDM as the DM. However, it will not start it right away.

On the other hand, active/inactive( and optionally failed) tells you the current state of the the service. After running `systemctl start lxdm`, LXDM actually runs, and its status is active.

Normally, when you first install a service, you would first test it by starting it. If it checks out, you would then enable it. That way, you avoid hanging your system during boot.