# iscsi.service - Active: inactive (dead)

Tags: systemd

What does `Active: inactive (dead)` mean when querying `systemctl`?

For example:

```
systemctl status iscsi.service
● iscsi.service - Login and scanning of iSCSI devices
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iscsi.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Does it mean it's misconfigured, not working, not started, or some other problem?

Comment: see [Differences between inactive vs disabled and active vs enabled services](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159174)